# Reinstatement as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I recently asked SE to [reinstate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-a-moderator-to-request-reinstatement-or-appeal-a-removal) me as a moderator here on Skeptics and the request was approved. I was one of the original pro-tem moderators when the site was created and became an elected moderator [in the first election after we graduated](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/1). I stepped down in January 2020.

Just in case you were wondering who that strange new diamond moderator was that recently appeared on the site. There is no conspiracy here, just a plain old reinstatement ;-).

Answer (score 4):

BE GONE EVIL DEMON.  THERE SHALL BE NO MAD SCIENTISTS HERE IN SKEPTICS ANYMORE.

J/K welcome back :) we missed you