# Transparency and proper procedure: why are moderators and their duties so mocked and tainted on SkepticsSE, leaving users clueless and powerless?

Tags: discussion

What's going on here?

1. First a moderator gets just (re)-appointed, without any election?

Note: this is not against *the actual person* getting that job then, but it is firmly against this example of arbitrary, in-transparent and wanton ignorance towards the community of users here. Proper procedure looks different.

2. Now, a moderator who has been properly serving his elected position since 2020 loses his diamond without any communication for the user base to make that transparent in any way?

Not even a short note that we are experiencing 'technical difficulties' and that moderators continue to be 'safe and effective'?

That no info is coming forward on this leads to one likely possibility:

Just monica-ing another mod surely leaves another sour taste. Intransparency is unacceptable.

Answer (score 15):

Fredsbend resigned, there was no intervention from SE or the other mods here. Whether he wants to comment publicly beyond that is entirely up to him.

I was reinstated according to [a defined process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-a-moderator-to-request-reinstatement-or-appeal-a-removal). Any moderator that resigned is free to ask for reinstatement. And I was previously elected, so there is not really a big difference between not resigning at all and resigning and being reinstated later.

Comment: Intransparency remains inacceptable, and this 'just because SE 'defines'' doesn't change that this 'process' is bad, as visible with [926 downvotes on the initial decree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336177/373864) and plenty on this newer 'definition'. This does mock the user base and the declarations of anything "…is run by you" on self-image pages of SE. If the other (ex)mod wants to comment himself or not, that level of significant mod changes take place _must_ be communicated. It was not. As it looks, no one here seems interested enough to improve on this deplorable attitude?

Comment: @LangLаngС You would perhaps be better directing your ire at the people who make the rules, you're essentially shooting the messenger here. But what I will say is no moderator owes you an explanation, it is an entirely volunteer position which owes you personally (nor the community as a whole) anything.

Comment: @LangLаngС The reason the process was controversial was entirely different, the process covers several cases. The reinstatement of a moderator that stepped down voluntarily is a case that was not controversial at all as far as I observed. I'm not aware of any substantive complaints about it.

Comment: @Jamiec In case you misunderstood what I explicitly stated in Q: this is not about 'MadSci getting the job', so there is no 'ire' in that direction. 'Those making the rules' don't listen (meta post is locked eg, many 'rules' even openly "not up for discussion", so why bother asking metaSE at all?). Even your own "_those_ making the rules" illustrates the despicable mushroom management of users from SE. 'The process' keeps us in the dark & feeds us smelly detritus, 0-announcement mod 'resignations' strike the same chord. If SekpticsSE wants to be as bad as MetaSE, that's not good.

Comment: @Schmuddi My reinstatement [was mentioned in a meta post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4784/5), mostly to avoid any confusion. Posting when you leave as a mod has always been left up to the mods, some mods like me for example prefer not to make a big deal out of it.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks. In fact, I now do remember reading that post.

Comment: @Schmuddi Some mods, like MadScientist, _[do post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334305/373864)_ 'when they leave', just not in the community where that matters most (here, bad)? MadSci posted here when re-surfacing (good), but now seems to re-write history over [the controversy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/373864), that [still crashes across](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5577/66575) [the network](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5571/66575) with the same sound this post generates? Transparency seems overrated & community of users mocked for demanding it? Worse.

Comment: @LangLаngС well at least you know that Fredsbend resigned. On ELL [we still don't know](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/and-then-there-were-two) what happened to our moderator Eddie Kal... everything has to be  clouded in secrecy by SE.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In the case of Monica SE did make public statements about the removal, and those made everything much worse. A general policy of not commenting on mod removal makes sense, even though it might make the whole thing look more secretive than it actually is.

Comment: The resulting anger and the ensuing diaspora of moderators happened not because SE informed users that Monica had lost her privileges but because they did not or would not make amends *in private* or in public. The "we cannot be seen to lose face" was SE no.1 priority. Monica could have been trusted to not reveal the ins and outs.